# Memory not requested being allocated

Tags: c, memory

I have written a simple memory allocator, basically creates a chain of allocated blocks, they are linked together using pointers stored in a metadata `struct` before the allocated area.

The code works perfectly, and I am able to allocate chain of blocks of size `sz` which are then freed with another function written by me.

The problem is that I noticed, using `vmmap` command, that apparently memory is being allocated by `malloc` without explicitly requesting it. Here's a paste of various `vmmap`, taken at different point of the program execution:

```
## before first alloc
# this has been taken before any allocation happens in the code.

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             9388K        see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K <-- we start with 8K
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             149.8M

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x10ad37000      9216K        363        27K      0%

=======================================================================

## after first alloc
# this is after the chain allocation.

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             18.2M <-- why the hell does malloc() increase?
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                        8200K <-- this is expected, we allocate memory with vm_allocate()
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             166.8M

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x10ad37000      18.0M        364        31K      0%

=======================================================================

## after chain release

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             19.2M <-- malloc increases even more?!?
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K <-- after chain release
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             159.8M <-- but why has total size increased?

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x10ad37000      19.0M        364        31K      0%
```

I am on OS X and I use the `vm_allocate` routine to allocate memory for my blocks. So, as expected, the `VM_ALLOCATE` section in `vmmap` shows that after the chain release, the section memory returns to initial size, i.e. 8K. I never call `malloc` in my code.

But apparently, the `MALLOC` section size increases after the allocation! And it never frees. The total size, after the chain release is 10MB more than before the chain allocation.

Has anyone idea of why could this happen? I don't think that the `vm_allocate` routine calls `malloc`, that wouldn't make sense. Thanks in advance for any help!

#### Testing without allocating code

I actually commented out all the allocating code that my program did, basically left an empty `main` function. Then repeated the three `vmmap` checks for my program. Results:

```
REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             9388K        see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             149.8M

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x105379000      9216K        363        27K      0%

=========================================================================

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             10.2M        see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             150.8M

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x105379000      10.0M        363        27K      0%

=========================================================================

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             11.2M        see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC (admin)                       24K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                              668K
__LINKEDIT                         70.2M
__TEXT                             5860K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             151.8M

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x105379000      11.0M        363        27K      0%
```

`VM_ALLOCATE` region now doesn't increase, as expected, no one is calling `vm_allocate`. But, as you can see, the `MALLOC` region still increases! Even without my code. It does grow less than before, i.e. 11MB instead of 18MB.

This means that my code has some direct influence on it, but what could it be? Maybe library functions are calling `malloc`? I use some `printf` in my allocating code, and I know functions like `printf` call `malloc`, but why then the is memory not released?

### EDIT - Adding my code

Sorry for not including it before, and sorry if it is a total mess, I have written this in around two hours and it's my first attempt at creating a custom allocator.

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>

#define BLOCK_NO 2048

typedef struct mem_block {
    struct mem_block *next;
    unsigned int sz;
    unsigned int free:1;
} mem_block_t;

void *alloc_block(vm_size_t size)
{
    void *block_addr=NULL;
    mem_block_t metadata;
    vm_address_t *start_addr=0;

    vm_allocate(mach_task_self_, (vm_address_t*)&start_addr, size, 1);
    block_addr=(start_addr);
    metadata.next=(void*)NULL;
    metadata.sz=(unsigned int)size;
    metadata.free=0x0;

    memcpy(block_addr, (mem_block_t*)&metadata, sizeof(mem_block_t));

    return block_addr+sizeof(mem_block_t);
}

void dealloc_block(void *block_addr)
{
    unsigned int sz=0;
    vm_address_t start_addr = (vm_address_t)block_addr-sizeof(mem_block_t);
    memcpy(&sz, (void*)start_addr+sizeof(mem_block_t*), sizeof(sz));
    vm_deallocate(mach_task_self_, start_addr, sz);
}

void *alloc_block_chain(unsigned int blocks, vm_size_t size)
{
    void *head=NULL, *old_block=NULL, *curr=NULL;
    head = alloc_block(size);
    old_block = head;
    for (int i=0; i<blocks-1; i++) {
        curr = alloc_block(size);
        ((mem_block_t*)old_block)->next=curr;
        old_block=curr;
    }

    return head;
}

void dealloc_block_chain(void *block_addr_start)
{
    int cnt=0;
    void *curr=NULL, *old_block=NULL;
    curr=block_addr_start;
    while(1) {
        if (old_block) {
            dealloc_block(old_block);
            malloc_printf("dealloc'd block #%d: %p\n", cnt, old_block);
            cnt++;
        }
        if (!((mem_block_t*)curr)->next) {
            dealloc_block(curr);
            malloc_printf("dealloc'd final block: %p\n", curr);
            break;
        } else {
            old_block = curr;
            curr=((mem_block_t*)curr)->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    system("read -n 1 -s -p \"Press any key to continue...\";echo");

    void *start = alloc_block_chain(BLOCK_NO, PAGE_SIZE);
    void *curr=start;

    for (int i=0; i<BLOCK_NO; i++) {
        malloc_printf("block #%d: %p\n", i, curr);
        curr = ((mem_block_t*)curr)->next;
    }

    system("read -n 1 -s -p \"Press any key to continue...\";echo");

    dealloc_block_chain(start);

    system("read -n 1 -s -p \"Press any key to continue...\";echo");

    return 0;
}
```

#### Possible solution

You can see I use `malloc_printf` in the code. I previously called `printf` there. The `malloc_printf` function is similar to `printf` but avoids calling `malloc`.

This seems to fix the leak! I will do more testing later, but for what I have seen the problem could indeed be OS X implementation of `printf`.

Comment: "I know functions like `printf` call `malloc`"... how do you know that?

Comment: I have worked with function hooking/interposing, and noticed many times that `printf` implementation calls `malloc`. At least, on OS X!

Comment: Ah yes, it may do so for multibyte/wide string conversions.

Comment: @KerrekSB better than opening a file like the pre VS2015 `printf` did on MSVC

Comment: @barakmanos you're right. sorry for that! Added the code :)

Comment: What's `block_addr+sizeof(mem_block_t)`? Does that even compile???

Comment: I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04.  There is no malloc/malloc.h nor mach/mach.h header files.   I.E. those header files are not portable.

Comment: regarding this line: 'memcpy(block_addr, (mem_block_t*)&metadata, sizeof(mem_block_t));'  the system function: memcpy() is expecting three parameters (void*, const void*, size_t) so why add a (incorrect) cast of the second parameter to 'mem_block_t*'?

Comment: Suggest a careful review of pointer math and its' implications, as there are several 'iffy' calculations being performed, including this one: 'memcpy(&sz, (void*)start_addr+sizeof(mem_block_t*), sizeof(sz));' which copies 4 *or 8) bytes and mis-casts the second parameter of memcpy() and (probably) does not copy the expected data.

Answer (score 1):

The `vm_deallocate` function deallocates a region of virtual memory in the specified task's address space. The region starts at the beginning of the virtual page containing address and ends at the end of the virtual page containing `address + size - 1`. Because of this rounding to virtual page boundaries, the amount of memory deallocated may be greater than size.
I think references wont be cleared and this is why other threads can still reference to this address space.if you run the mentioned program continuously it may lead to crash as well as the reference should also needs to be cleared.
Correct me if I am wrong.